# Using JavaScript and sinon How do you spy on methods called in the constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I really need help with the following code - This is not pasted from my program its off the top of my head but I think it clearly demonstrates the problem (and I believe it to be fully accurate). When I request the value of "spy.called" it ignores the call made in the constructor function. How do I code this so that the call inside the constructor is registered by the spy?

OR if not possible what approach should I take? Example code greatly appreciated - Many thanks - Been banging my head all day with this!

```
function MyClass() {
  var self = this;
  this.myFunc = function() {
    console.log("hi");
  }
  function init() {
    self.myFunc();
  }
  init();
}


var spy = sinon.spy(new MyClass(), "myFunc");
console.log(spy.called);  // true if the spy was called at least once
// ABOVE OUTPUTS FALSE - IT FAILS TO REGISTER THE CALL IN THE CONSTRUCTOR!
spy.myFunc();
console.log(spy.called);
// ABOVE OUTPUTS TRUE AS EXPECTED
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that when the method `myFunc` is called the spy doesn't exist yet. Your code is equivalent to :

```
var c = new MyClass()
var spy = sinon.spy(c, "myFunc");
```

Clearly the spy is not in place when the constructor is called.

To solve this problem you can move the method `myFunc` in the prototype of the `MyClass` object and then spy the methods in the prototype.

For example:

```
function MyClass() {
  this.init();
}

MyClass.prototype.myFunc = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}

MyClass.prototype.init = function() {
   this.myFunc();
}

var myFuncSpy = sinon.spy(MyClass.prototype, "myFunc");
var initSpy = sinon.spy(MyClass.prototype, "init");

var c = new MyClass();
console.log(myFuncSpy.called); // TRUE
console.log(initSpy.called);  // TRUE
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/och191so/1/ 
Open the console to see the result.

Comment: A massive thankyou for this answer - I could never have come up with this solution - got this working in my code now - many many thanks :) The fiddle was great - couldnt have expected a better answer if I was paying you! A true gentleman

Answer (score 2):

I think you should redesign your class a bit. You can either accept myFunc in constructor argument (only if it makes sense from point of usage) or you can set it on MyClass' prototype:

```
function MyClass() {
    function init() {
        this.myFunc();
    }
    init();
}

MyClass.prototype.myFunc = function() {
    console.log("hi");
}

var spy = sinon.spy(MyClass.prototype, "myFunc");
new MyClass();
console.log(spy.called);
```